# Microsoft graph calender api - read events of all users with email address

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I have a of question on Microsoft Graph API . Is it possible to get calendar events of all outlook or office 365 users with my personal account ( Using my account to register an application in azure). I have a node application like to read users calendar events with their email address. Also let me know if we can create new event for other users

Comment: For your scenario, you need to have multi-tenant based Azure AD application, so you can access both personal/hotmail + Office 365 mailboxes and read users calendars using that. Here's a related sample, using that you can get it started - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-aspnet-daemon-web-app.

Comment: Yes, you can create new event/calendar items for other users as well, using Microsoft Graph API!!